# Getting error from the FileUtils.remove_dir()

Tags: ruby

I wrote the below code, to meet my some requirement:

```
src = "E:\\Download"
dest = "E:\\Scripts\\original"  #"E:\WIPData\Ruby\Scripts\"

FileUtils.copy_entry(src, dest, preserve = false, dereference_root = false, remove_destination = false)
FileUtils.remove_dir(src , force = false)
```

But getting the below error 4 out of 10 times. Couldn't understand why such error I am getting:

***Error***

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1406:in `unlink': Permission denied - 
E:\\Download/BASIC USES OF THE ENGLISH TENSES.pdf.pa
rt (Errno::EACCES)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1406:in `block in remove_fil
e'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1414:in `platform_support'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1405:in `remove_file'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1394:in `remove'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:770:in `block in remove_entr
y'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to remove your src directory, but you do not have filesystem permissions to do so.

Comment: Yes, I want to delete the `download` folder only,after copied it to destination folder.It works sometimes,but not always.

Comment: I suppose you're using NTFS, so read this http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions-file-folder.htm. I really suspect, that you simply don't owe some files in that directory.

Comment: I do have access on that folders, As I am creating the source folder on runtime to download the data, and when download completed,I am moving all the files to the destination files and and the source one to delete. But it sometime happens and sometimes not.

Comment: Could you show more (full) code, how you create your src folder (what method and what params are you using with it).

Answer (score 0):

Do you double click the script or run it from cmd/cygwin? If you run your script with a double click, you could try right-clicking your script and clicking "Run as administrator"; it might fix the permissions error.